# How to pass epoch-dependent parameters to a custom layer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a [k-sparse autoencoder](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5663) in Keras (with Tensorflow as the backend). The authors of the original paper suggest that the sparsity of the middle layer should be increased progressively during training:

> Suppose we are aiming for a sparsity level of k = 15.
>   Then, we start off with a large sparsity level (e.g.
>   k = 100) for which the k-sparse autoencoder can train
>   all the hidden units. We then linearly decrease the
>   sparsity level from k = 100 to k = 15 over the first
>   half of the epochs. This initializes the autoencoder in
>   a good regime, for which all of the hidden units have
>   a significant chance of being picked. Then, we keep
>   k = 15 for the second half of the epochs. With this
>   scheduling, we can train all of the filters, even for low
>   sparsity levels.

My custom layer looks like this and works for a static sparsity level `k` for all epochs:

```
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import backend as K

class KSparse(Layer):
    def __init__(self, k=15, **kwargs):
        self.k = k
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return K.in_train_phase(self.k_sparsify(inputs), inputs)

    def k_sparsify(self, inputs):
        k = self.k
        kth_smallest = K.tf.contrib.framework.sort(inputs)[..., K.shape(inputs)[-1]-1-k]
        return inputs * K.cast(K.greater(inputs, kth_smallest[:, None]), K.floatx())

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

I have an array of the desired sparsity levels per epoch and a callback that accesses the current epoch:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

def sparsity_level_per_epoch(n_epochs):
    return np.hstack((np.linspace(100, 15, n_epochs // 2, dtype=np.int),
                      np.repeat(15, n_epochs // 2)))


nth_epoch = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch, logs: epoch)
```

During training, how do I pass the sparsity level of the current epoch to `KSparse`?

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem and I found a similar question on [this Github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5206). The replier suggests to add a non trainable weight with the epoch counter which is updated every epoch. I am still searching how to implement it though. Will post an answer here if I am able to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically change the layer properties because the computation graph is statically generated based on `k` at generation time. In other words, the `k_sparsify` is applied with a fixed `k`, the `call` method is actually called once. If you have an external changing parameter, one option would be to make it an input:

```
sparsity_level = Input(shape=(...))
# ...
out = KSparse()([x, sparsity_level])
```

and pass `sparsity_level` tensor to the `KSparse` layer so the value is now dependant on the tensor and not a class property. You can, as you already did, compute these levels offline prior to training and pass as an input now.

```
# inside KSparse you get a list of inputs
def call(self, inputs):
  x, sparsity_level = inputs # the things we pass in
  # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see. Could you flesh out how I can use this additional `Input` layer to dynamically pass the epoch's sparsity level to `KSparse`?

Comment: You just pass a list of inputs including the sparsity level which you can use separately in the call method, I've added some more code to help with that. I'm assuming you are using the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

Comment: I am using the functional API. I had got as far as what you have included in your edit, but I still don't see how to assign different values to `sparsity_level` by slicing `sparsity_level_per_epoch` with the training epoch number. Could you provide some code of how/where that is done?

Comment: It's like passing any other data, for every data point you will now give a sparsity level computed a priori and pass as input. This all happens in NumPy external to Keras. You might have to repeat the sparsity levels for each epoch for every datapoint to have sparsity level for every datapoint.